# django filter from two fields with single input

Tags: django

I'm having table with fields skills and title. I want to filter these fields with single input.

```
models.py
class job(model.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)

search.html
<form>
<input type="text" name="skills" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

views.py
jobs.objects.filter(skills__icontains=request.GET['skills'],title__icontains=request.GET['skills'])
```

while i trying this code can't get output. I need output when entering title or skills in input box it matches with both skills and title. it should be a single input.some one help me..

Comment: You probably shouldn't call the form field `skills` if it's being used to search on the job title too. Call it something like `search`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code searches for jobs where BOTH title AND skills contain `request.GET['skills']`. To search for jobs where title OR skills (or both) contain `request.GET['skills']`, you have to use `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
search = request.GET['skills']
        #     skills contain search  OR  title contains search
query = Q(skills__icontains=search ) | Q(title__icontains=search )
job.objects.filter(query)
```